# Star Trek Into Darkness, Nibiran Sacred Scroll?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

Considering the volcano rescue [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHKUJPRtewI), and the reaction of the Nibiran to the repossession of their sacred scroll, and then their reaction upon seeing the USS Enterprise rise out of the sea, namely: them letting go and tossing-aside of their scared scroll whilst drawing a sketch of the Enterprise on the ground as an expression of worship, is it correct that the image on the sacred scroll is a depiction of a previous encounter with extraterrestrial life?

Kirk claims to not know the significance of the scroll, yet - if he knew that the Enterprise had become the object of worship, he might have realised the sacred scroll could have been a depiction of another spacefaring species.

Looking closely, you can see elements of the sacred scroll painted onto their faces and backs.

[image]

Comment: I've added a picture of the original prop; https://branded.liveauctiongroup.com/STAR-TREK-INTO-DARKNESS-2013-Captain-Kirk-s-Nibiran-Scroll_i28422572

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks. I found this wider view too: https://dygtyjqp7pi0m.cloudfront.net/i/29998/28422572_1.jpg?v=8D5A4AE3D6B4C20

Comment: US Vengeance? I don't recall seeing the USS Vengeance until much later in the movie.

Comment: May be that is the answer https://treknews.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/stlv-2014-cosplay-nibirans.jpg )))))))

Comment: I don't see any particular reason why this fictional religion should be based on extra-terrestrial visitors, any more than than real religions are. Of course, [some people _do_ claim that link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_astronauts), but they are, to put it politely, not mainstream. I assumed the (rather tasteless) implication was that seeing a giant monster/machine (the Enterprise) rising from the sea made them immediately discard their religion and start a new cult, which tells you nothing about what their old religion was. Am I missing some other evidence?